# Como capturar datos de un archivo CSV y luego esos datos ingresarlos a una db MySQL?

Tags: python, api, csv

Hola estoy intentando capturar datos de un archivo CSV para luego ocupar estos datos dentro de una bdd en MySQL workbench, necesito hacerle un insert o update dependiendo del valor del primer parámetro "A" o "U". Todo dentro de FastAPI. Alguna sugerencia u opinion?, por favor necesito ayuda!.

A continuación dejo el código.

```
@router.post('/file-db/', status_code=201)
def file_csvdata_save(file: UploadFile = File(...), session: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    try:
        ## fecha = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        any_file = f'{file.filename}'

        # SEPARO EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO CON SU EXTENSION ##
        test_filename = os.path.splitext(any_file)
        extension = test_filename[1]  # EXTENSION ##

        ## VALIDACION DEL ARCHIVO CSV , SI NO ES CSV ARROJA ERROR 400 ##
        if extension == '.csv':

            ## PROCESO DE LECTURA DE ARCHIVO CSV ##
            try:

                ## CAPTURA DE DATOS DEL ARCHIVO CSV ##
                Path(
                    f"resources/files/{any_file}_file/").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                aux_path = "resources/files/{}_file/{}".format(
                    any_file, any_file)

                with open(aux_path, mode='wb+') as f:
                    f.write(file.file.read())

                print("NAME ANY_FILE: ", any_file)
                
                with open(aux_path, mode='r') as csv_file:
                    csvfile = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                    

                    for row in csvfile:

                        ## INSERT (post)
                        if row[0] == 'A':
                            print("Logica insert!")
                            # all_value.append(value2)

                            ## TESTING ##
                            session_data = models.PortabilidadInfo(
                                msisdn=row[1]+row[2], operator_id=row[4], last_upt=date.today().strftime(row[7], "%Y-%m-%d"))
                            print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: ", session_data)
                            session.add(session_data)
                            session.commit()

                            #######################################################

                        ## UPDATE (put)
                        elif row[0] == 'U':
                            print("Logica update!")
                            ##print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: ", value2)
                            # all_value.append(value2)
                            #######
                        else:
                            print("A surgido un error!")
                session.close()

                ## print("XXXXXXXXXXXXX: ", all_value, " type: ", type(all_value))

            except Exception as e:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')
        else:
            print("File_extension: ", extension,
                  "RESPONSE: No CSV extension!")
            return "File_extension: ", extension, "RESPONSE: No CSV extension!"

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')
```

ERROR:

```
local variable 'portabilidad_info' referenced before assignment

←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:54351 - "←[1mPOST /file-db/ HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m400 Bad Request←[0m
```

Comment: fijate que con phpmyadmin se haria mas facil eso, pero ahi en mysql debe haber una de importacion para archivos csv

Comment: @ElVecinoTlalixcoyan Como es eso? tengo todas las importaciones necesarias para el flujo.

Comment: en su momento use este video pero tengo entendido que agregas el csv a tarves de exportar o importar external files https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31DuU-98XtY

Comment: @MatiasGonzalez cual es el problema que presentas? Yo no vi ninguna pregunta en esta publicación

Comment: Agregando a lo que dijo Christian, algunos no respondemos por que simplemente no sabemos del tema. No es que seas ignorado por que si...

Comment: @Christian Hola cristian, gracias por responder. Mi problema reside en que me aparecen errores de Bad Request y no se ingresan los datos, la pregunta seria que estoy haciendo mal. En pocas palabras solo quiero que luego de capturar los datos que contanga un csv cualquiera, esos datos poder ingresarlos correctamente a los campos del mysql workbench

Comment: Por favor agrega el error a tu pregunta y si es posible más detalles :)

Comment: @Christian, Edite la pregunta, gracias! , espero que me puedan orientar un poco mejor.

Comment: Ok, eso sucede por que tu mismo generar el error cuando ocurre una excepción. Para poder depurar el código te recomiendo colocar un `print(e)` antes de lanzar la excepción. Cuando tengas esos logs edita tu pregunta añadiendo lo que sale.

Comment: Acabo de ver que pones unos detalles al generar el error 400, ¿que te sale en tu navegador?

Comment: @Christian ya edite la pregunta con el print(e) de error. Dentro del navegador (Swagger de FastApi), me aparece el mismo error un BadRequest 400

Comment: Tienes una variable no definida -_-, verifica tu código.

Comment: @Christian Si, ya resolvi eso. Pero aun no logro como hacer para que ingrese los datos a la bdd , nada me resulta. Tienes algun metodo que hayas probado y haya funcionado?

Comment: No hay metodo que funcione mágicamente, debes de conocer el error para poder hallar la solución. Si ya corregiste la variable ahora se supone que debe aparecer otro tipo de error. Por favor vuelve a editar tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pude solucionar el problema, con harto sudor y prueba y error logre llegar a un resultado aceptable por ahora. Adjunto la porcion del codigo necesario para un INSERT.

```
                for row in csvfile:
                    value2: CreateAndUpdatePortabilidad
                    value2 = {
                        'msisdn': row[1]+row[2],
                        'operator_id': row[4],
                        'last_upt': date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    }
                    try:

                        ## INSERT (post)
                        if row[0] == 'A':
                            print("Logica insert!")
                            ##print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: ", value2, type(value2))
                            data = portabilidad_service.create_data(
                                session, obj_in=value2)
                            ##print("WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW", data, type(data))

                        ## UPDATE (put)
                        elif row[0] == 'U':
                            print("Logica update!")
                            value2: Portabilidad
                            print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: ",
                                  value2, type(value2))
                            ''' data = portabilidad_service.update_data(
                                session, obj_in=value2) '''

                        else:
                            print("A surgido un error!")

                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'{e}')

                return data
```